# Can laws of physics work in a realm without space and time?

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

I think this question is a lot philosophical. However, i am asking it out of curiosity. Every physics equation that i have come across has the component representing space or time in it. Don't bash me for asking it. I am just curious.

Comment: Say a single law which doesn't use the "space" and "time", at least indirectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem unnecessary but I'll try to answer it in brief. The notion of time and space exists because  it helps to model the world we see around us and describe them, which is the essence of Physics. It's true that time and space is needed in conditions involving coordinate systems or time symmetry indicating energy conservation by Noether's Theorem.

Essentially static(unchanging with time) conditions can be modeled without time and stationary conditions too(without space) may be modeled without a need for space or coordinate system. Like suppose calculating the *magnitude* of acceleration that an object will have with certain resultant force applied to it given by $ F=ma$, but if we don't use space hence distance with direction and time we can't really model the situation further. So without space and time you can say Physics' laws are **incomplete**.